# coffeescript how to set binding" to a child class in a callback function defined in parent class

Tags: coffeescript

I'd like to changing the binding of the callback function in a child class so that the following code indicates 20, rather than 10:

```
class A 
  @in = 10
  @b: =>
    alert(@in)

class B extends A
  @in = 20

  @w: ->
    window.setTimeout(@b,500)

B.w()
```

If I 'thin-arrow' the definition of A.b, then the binding is to the timeout calling function so @in is undefined.  When I fat-arrow it, it binds to the parent class A.  I would like it to bind to the child class B, without redefining the method in the child class.

Thanks

Comment: Any particular reason that everything is set up to use class methods? Your `@in = 10` is sort of like a class variable but not really.

Comment: Yes, in this particular design there are class methods and instance methods and I'm trying to do this with the class methods.  It behaves as expected (I do get 20 in the equivalent example) if I'm using instance methods.

Comment: `class` is a bit of a lie in CoffeeScript, there's really no such thing. Your `@in = 10` is the same as saying `A.in = 10` so there's no prototype involved and hence no inheritance relationship to use when resolving `@in` inside `@b`.

Comment: True that class is really "class-ish", but B.b() does return 20 if I define B with thin-arrows in A:Problem is that if it's defined with thin-arrows, then it doesn't have the right binding in the callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best you can do is force the appropriate binding manually when you set up your `setTimeout` call. Drop the `=>` when defining `@b` in `A`:

```
class A 
  #...
  @b: -> alert(@in)
```

And then set the binding in `B` when you call `setTimeout`:

```
class B extends A
  #...
  @w: ->
    f = => @b()
    window.setTimeout(f, 500)
```

I think that's as close as you can get using CoffeeScript's pseudo-class-methods.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/Y6S8D/